# Input type file causes long loading

Tags: html, file

On my webpage user can upload some file.
What is really annoying when file dialog opens, the cursor signals me, shown as circle not an arrow and being very "turbulent" , that something is loading.
The same is when I close the file dialog again.

This is my code.

```
input type='file' id="btnFile" name="file"
```

Comment: Maybe It's the PC Isuue ?

Comment: hm. Could be the case .

Comment: maybe the reason is, the PC is working slow. So You see the Waiting Cursor.

Comment: I just tried in chrome and IE and in both it stays for 10 seconds. It is horrible. It would make the user crazy  My PC is very fast.

Comment: I think it is a normal thing.. don't worry for this.. 
if you are worried about it please share the link. I'll check in on my PC.

Comment: what I also have to add. BtnFile click is triggered by jquery  $("input[type='file']").trigger('click');

Comment: Not necessary ..

Comment: but also this should not be the reason for this annoying cursor loading.

Comment: yes... maybe ...